# How do you add foreign keys to MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my code ATM,

```
CREATE TABLE session( Code CHAR(2), 
Date DATE PRIMARY KEY, 
Room VARCHAR(30) null, 
FOREIGN KEY(code) REFERENCES module (code) 
); 
CREATE TABLE module( 
Code CHAR(2) PRIMARY KEY, 
Name VARCHAR(30) not null, 
Cost DECIMAL(8,2) not null, 
Credits TINYINT not null,
Course_code CHAR(3), FOREIGN KEY(Course_code) REFERENCES take(code) 
);
```

I keep on getting a 1005 error, "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formatted"
does anyone know how to fix this???

Comment: In normal SQL, there would be no comma.  In MySQL, you might need a separate line for a foreign key constraint.

Comment: When you create the session table, the module table does not exsist, tberefore you cannot reference the module table with a foreign key.

Comment: How can i reference it?

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/14mfc5j/9

Answer (score 1):

You used `CREATE TABLE module( Code CHAR(2) PRIMARY KEY,` but in another table, you used `REFERENCES module (code)`. I don't know if you noticed, but there is no `code` column. The correct is `Code`. Column's name is case sensitive.

My suggestion: change every `code` (with lower case) to `Code` (with initial upper case). Only to check if that's actually the problem.

Comment: tried it but nope, this is what mysql should be like